# how to implement WebSocket client reconnect after some time in Vertx?

Tags: java, websocket, vert.x

I'm connecting websocket server using vertx, but when connection closed/Server went down(temporarily) try to reconnect after some interval.

WebSocket code is :

```
public void start() throws Exception {

  HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
  MultiMap form = MultiMap.caseInsensitiveMultiMap();
  if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(header)) {
    header.forEach((k,v)-> {
      form.set(k, v);
    });
  }

  RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
     .setHost(host)
     .setPort(port)
     .setSsl(sslFlag)
     .setURI(uri);

  Handler<WebSocket> socket = new Handler<WebSocket>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(WebSocket event) {
      event.handler(data -> {
        currentCount = 0;
        LOGGER.info("Received data " + data.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
      });
    }
  };

  Handler<Throwable> exception = new Handler<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Throwable event) {
      LOGGER.error("Exception occured in Websocket connection, retrying count is {}", currentCount, event);
    }
  };
  client.websocket(options, form, socket , exception);

}
```

Above code Port, Host, etc are configured. Please any one suggest how to reconnect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can close the client and restart it:

```
public void start() {
    startClient(this.vertx);
}

private void startClient(Vertx vertx) {
    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();

    client.webSocket(8080, "localhost", "/", (ar) -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            WebSocket ctx = ar.result();
            ctx.textMessageHandler((msg) -> {
                System.out.println("Client " + msg);
                ctx.writeTextMessage("pong");
            }).exceptionHandler((e) -> {
                System.out.println("Restarting in 10 seconds");
                client.close();
                vertx.setTimer(10 * 1000, (__) -> {
                    startClient(vertx);
                });
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println(ar.cause());
        }
    });
}
```

**Edited:** Any exception when connecting time also retry will happen in below code.

```
private void startClient(Vertx vertx) {
  HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
  MultiMap form = MultiMap.caseInsensitiveMultiMap();
  if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(header)) {
    header.forEach((k,v)-> {
      form.set(k, v);
    });
  }
  RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
     .setHost(host)
     .setPort(port)
     .setSsl(sslFlag)
     .setURI(uri);
  client.websocket(options, form, (ctx) ->{
    ctx.textMessageHandler( msg -> {
      System.out.println("Client " + msg);
    }).exceptionHandler((e) -> {
        client.close();
        vertx.setTimer(waitTime * 10 * 1000, (__) -> {
          startClient(vertx);
        });
    });
  }, (exec) -> {
      vertx.setTimer(waitTime * 10 * 1000, (__) -> {
        startClient(vertx);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: I've tried this with `io.vertx:vertx-web-client:4.0.0-milestone4` it works, but with a drawback. Each call of setTimer leads to instantiation of new thread like `vert.x-eventloop-thread-99` while the previous threads hang